# Html select tag change arrow using sprite

Tags: html, css, webkit, css-sprites, html-select

I have a select tag that I would like to remove the arrow from and insert a different one for styling purposes; however, the arrow I am inserting is in a sprite. I would like to keep it in the sprite if possible to minimize server requests. I only need to see the example in chrome, and then I can transpose it into the firefox and IE forms of the solution. My attempt is in the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nbatothemax/r9XwX/8/) and the code is below.

HTML:

```
<select id="playerType">
    <option>Human</option>
    <option>Computer</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
#playerType {
    width: 81px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: url('http://goo.gl/8jNwT') no-repeat -250px -117px;
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to clip off the othre parts of the sprite other than the downwards chevron that I inserted. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a vertical sprite instead of a horizontal one.

Also, each image in the vertical sprite should have at least the height of the select element.
(In Your example they have).

Then you can use the vertical sprite right aligned.

Also, if you have other images in your sprite, not related to the dropdown, the image parts intended for the dropdowns should be as wide as your widest select element, the remainder of the space being filled with transparent, or whatever colour you wish to use. (it needs a little guessing/anticipating)

Comment: I'm trying to avoid editing the sprite and am trying to just find a css rule that can crop the sprite once I have it in position. Editing the sprite is nowhere near ideal because there are almost 100 icons in that sprite...Your answer isn't very clear either..

Comment: You can't clip the background image in the way you wish to in a select element. A possible workaround would be, to use a javascript implementation of the select element (which uses DOM elements to mimic the behavior of the select).

Comment: There is no way of "cropping" in css?

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't. The only CSS property close to this is `background-clip`, but it doesn't accept arbitrary areas.

Comment: Can you show the final .css that needed to display the image...I am trying the following and it not working:
.styled-select {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background-image: url('../../base/images/select.png');
  background-position: 0 -174px;
  background-color: @primaryColor;
//  background: url(@styledSelectImage) no-repeat right #fff;
  border: 0;
  height: 29px;
  width: 29px;
  line-height: 15px;
  padding: 7px 30px 6px 10px;
}
The OP's jsFiddle is not longer active